# Assume $f(x, \cdot) \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ for a.e. $x \in X$. Is $F: X \to L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot)$ Bochner measurable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let $T>0$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $X :=[0, T]$ and $Y:= \mathbb R^d$. Let $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ be the space of measurable functions $f:Y \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} := \sup_{y \in Y} \|1_{B(y, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(y, 1)$ is the open unit ball centered at $y$. Then $(L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), \|\cdot\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}})$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750669/the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-is-complete-w-r-t-the-norm-f) but [not separable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452474/is-the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-separable-w-r-t-the-norm-f). Let $(y_m)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. The sphere has Lebesgue measure $0$. Then by dominated convergence theorem (DCT),
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} = \sup_{m \in \mathbb N} \|1_{B(y_m, 1)} f\|_{L^p}
\quad \forall f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y).
$$

We have

> [Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452967/99469) Let $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $f(x, \cdot) \in L^p (Y)$ for a.e. $x \in X$. Then $F: X \to L^p (Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot)$ is measurable.

The proof of above **Theorem** relies on DCT for $L^p(Y)$. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/a/453180/99469) answer verifies that DCT does *not* hold for $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$.

Let $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $f(x, \cdot) \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ for a.e. $x \in X$. I would like to ask if the following statement holds, i.e.,

> **S1**  The map $F: X \to L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot)$ is measurable.

If not, does below weaker statement hold?

> **S2** The map $G: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \|f(x, \cdot)\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}$ is measurable.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

**Update** I have just proved that **S2** is true [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756754/assume-fx-cdot-in-lp-textloc-y-for-a-e-x-in-x-then-the-map). The remaining question is whether **S1** holds.